# AnkhSVN pending changes window throws error

Tags: visual-studio, ankhsvn

AnkhSVN 2.7.12815 installed fine from Tools>Extensions and Updates but when I want to open View>Other Windows>Pending Changes window I get below error.

I tried installing .msi file of older versions and early build 2.7.12821 version from site but they are not showing up in my Visual studio Community 2017 (version 12.6.0). My windows 10 is updated to latest Creators update 1709.

Any solutions?

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Ankh.UI.PendingChanges.PendingChangesToolControl.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at Ankh.VSPackage.AnkhToolWindowPane.get_Window()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.ToolWindowCreationResult..ctor(WindowPane window, UInt32 flags)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.CreateToolWindow(Type toolWindowType, Int32 id, UInt32 flags, Object context, Guid persistenceGuid)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.CreateToolWindow(Type toolWindowType, Int32 id, Object context)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.CreateToolWindow(Type toolWindowType, Int32 id)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.FindToolWindow(Type toolWindowType, Int32 id, Boolean create, ProvideToolWindowAttribute tool)
   at Ankh.VSPackage.AnkhSvnPackage.ShowToolWindow(AnkhToolWindow toolWindow, Int32 id, Boolean create)
   at Ankh.VSPackage.AnkhSvnPackage.ShowToolWindow(AnkhToolWindow window)
   at Ankh.Commands.UI.ShowToolWindows.OnExecute(CommandEventArgs e)
   at Ankh.Commands.CommandMapItem.OnExecute(CommandEventArgs e)
   at Ankh.Commands.CommandMapper.Execute(AnkhCommand command, CommandEventArgs e)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not alone. Look at:
[extension page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-303797.AnkhSVN-SubversionSupportforVisualStudio#review-details) and
[duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49156227/ankhsvn-crash-in-visual-studio-2017)

We have to wait for the repair.

Edit:
[Microsoft released fixed VS 15.6.1](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/207735/ankhsvn-2712815-failed-to-load-pending-changes-vie.html)