# AnkhSVN crash in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: exception, visual-studio-2017, ankhsvn

[W10 Pro x64 v1709, Visual Studio 2017 Community 15.6.0, AnkhSVN 2.7.12815.35086]

I am getting a crash at VS startup of AnkhSVN in VS 2017.  I believe this just started happening today - I don't remember it happening the last time I opened the IDE. Uninstall/reinstall of the extension doesn't help. Error msg when I attempt to open the Pending Changes window:

> AnkhSVN Exception
>   An internal error occurred:
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Stack trace:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Ankh.UI.PendingChanges.PendingChangesToolControl.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at Ankh.VSPackage.AnkhToolWindowPane.get_Window()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.ToolWindowCreationResult..ctor(WindowPane window, UInt32 flags)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.CreateToolWindow(Type toolWindowType, Int32 id, UInt32 flags, Object context, Guid persistenceGuid)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.CreateToolWindow(Type toolWindowType, Int32 id, Object context)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.CreateToolWindow(Type toolWindowType, Int32 id)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.FindToolWindow(Type toolWindowType, Int32 id, Boolean create, ProvideToolWindowAttribute tool)
   at Ankh.VSPackage.AnkhSvnPackage.ShowToolWindow(AnkhToolWindow toolWindow, Int32 id, Boolean create)
   at Ankh.VSPackage.AnkhSvnPackage.ShowToolWindow(AnkhToolWindow window)
   at Ankh.Commands.UI.ShowToolWindows.OnExecute(CommandEventArgs e)
   at Ankh.Commands.CommandMapItem.OnExecute(CommandEventArgs e)
   at Ankh.Commands.CommandMapper.Execute(AnkhCommand command, CommandEventArgs e)
```

Troubleshooting/repair suggestions?

Comment: try last nightly/daily build: https://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/daily/2.7.x/ and if it is still not fixed create a bug entry: http://ankhsvn.net/issues

Comment: @magicandre1981 I'm not seeing any builds which are VS17-compatible (VSIX installer)

Comment: @magicandre1981 MS has acknowledged it is their problem and there will be a VS update to fix it.

Comment: thanks. I use VisualSVN and don't have the issue here. So as a workaround change to it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This appears to be an issue introduced in the 15.6 release of Visual Studio 2017 - I see the same thing in Visual Studio 2017 Professional v15.6.

There is an open issue here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/207735/ankhsvn-2712815-failed-to-load-pending-changes-vie.html that is marked as under investigation.  I see 58 people are following the issue, so hopefully it will get some traction and be fixed soon.

Comment: Update on the issue: Microsoft has acknowledged the problem and said Visual Studio will be fixed "in an upcoming release."

Answer (score 3):

[Microsoft released fixed VS 15.6.1](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/207735/ankhsvn-2712815-failed-to-load-pending-changes-vie.html)

Answer (score 2):

I just committed a fix. I think you can work around this issue by unchecking the checkbox to add all files in the initial commit in the dialog where you select the location. (This used to be the default some time ago)

This issue will be fixed in the next release, and I’ll try to get one out over the next two weeks. I think VS 2017 should update AnkhSvn automatically unless you explicitly disabled this yourself.

Source URL :- https://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=582&dsMessageId=614598